# How to develop these button

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How to develop these buttons in the new sharepoint wiki page, any tutorial?
[image]
Thanks
Petre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could develop SPFx webpart for modern page.

Here is the guideline:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using?

If you are using **Latest SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint 2016 online**.

Directly in **Site Action** gear, select **Add a page** it will create modern site page in that you can see that *button*.

**Note:** Don't choose **switch to classic mode** when you are opening **Site content** or **View All Site Content** in left-bottom corner it will show, don't select that classic mode.